# python scipy eigs : return eigenvector after maximum number of iterations whatever the convergence tolerance

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvector, arpack

I would like to get eigenvectors of a sparse symmetric matrix with the best precision affordable in a given time.
Currently I use the following with `scipy.sparse.eigsh`:

```
evals, evecs = eigsh(MyMatrix, 2,which='LM' ,tol=1.e-15, maxiter=1000000)
```

If it does not converge to `tol` precision by `maxiter` iterations, it raises an `ArpackNoConvergence` error which contains the eigenvectors/values that have converged, but not the ones that did not. Yet, I prefer to have the vector with precision `1.e-14` instead of `1.e-15` rather than no vector at all. Is there a way to force returning the eigenvectors that have not converged yet (perhaps with another library) ?
Like in Matlab, where the `eigs` function returns the eigenvectors anyway, with just an additional Warning if the desired precision is not reached.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The [`ArpackNoConvergence`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.ArpackNoConvergence.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.ArpackNoConvergence) exception has `.eigenvalues` and `.eigenvectors` attributes that contain the partial results:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh, ArpackNoConvergence

M = np.random.RandomState(0).randn(100, 100)

try:
    w, v = eigsh(M, 5, maxiter=20)
except ArpackNoConvergence as e:
    print(e)
    w = e.eigenvalues
    v = e.eigenvectors
    print(w.shape, v.shape)
```

Prints:

```
ARPACK error -1: No convergence (21 iterations, 2/5 eigenvectors converged)
((2,), (100, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks! But what I want is to access the eingenvalue/vector that was being calculated and did not fully converge. The exception only contains the ones that have converged to the required precision. I would like to have the best precision available in a given number of iterations.

Comment: I suppose that one quick workaround would be to iteratively reduce the tolerance until `eigs` no longer converges within the specified number of iterations. Aside from that, I think it ought to be possible to get the partially converged eigenvalues/vectors by manually constructing a [`scipy.sparse.linalg.arpack._SymmetricArpackParams`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/arpack.py#L370-L585) object, calling `.iterate()` on it, then recovering the eigenvalues/vectors using `.extract()` when the iteration fails.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that quickaround.  Okay, thanks a lot !

Comment: @AntPlante  @ali_m The discussion above looks very helpful. Just wanted to check if there are any updates on this question. I was still not able to get a non-converged answer. The `extract()` method does not even generate a partially converged answer.

Comment: @eafit No update so far for me. The fix I use is to set the number of Lanczos vectors (`ncv` keyword argument of eigsh) higher than default, which makes it converge but run longer in my problem,

`eigsh(MyMatrix, 2, which='LM', tol=1.e-15, ncv=15)`